# Project resources.{LANG}.resx does not auto generate Designer.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version, auto-generate

Any attempt to create a language resources, the `custom tool` does not generate the *.Designer.cs. The file is totally empty.

**This problem only happens on resources with the resource format {RESOURCENAME}.{LANG}.resx** .

[image]

My Custom Tool defined on resources: `ResXFileCodeGenerator` (I tried to change to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`and does not help)

I tried a plugin called `RunCustomToolOnBuild`, but no success.

other solutions with similar problems does not fit with this problem so far.

Comment: Just so you know this question makes zero sense to me! It needs a lot of elaboration

Comment: Ok, thank you for your intervention

Comment: Are you trying to implement localization?

Comment: Yes, but that is working correctly and my XF proj is working fine with current resources. I Guess this problem is nothing to do with Xamarin. Its more like VS, .netframeworks stuff imo

Comment: Try repairing it once may be?